WhatsApp API for reading user messages to create 3rd party WhatsApp client
I am trying to create a WhatsApp client similar to 'WhatsApp web' where a user can log in and receive messages. So far only options I found is whatsapp-web.js.
The issue is it uses WhatsApp web in the background and may get banned by WhatsApp.
Is there any correct way I can achieve this?

No, unfortunately there is not, WhatsApp is a proprietary piece of software and Facebook/Meta have made it very clear that they have no interest in providing a stable API to normal users wishing to build a custom client.
You could attempt to reverse engineer their API yourself, but in the process of testing/prodding their servers there is a pretty good chance they will notice and block you. Arguably your best bet is indeed whatsapp-web.js which has already done most of the work of reverse engineering the Whatsapp Web client for you.
Of course whatsapp-web.js is not officially supported by Whatsapp and may break or result in your account getting banned so it is really only good for a personal hobby projects and absolutely should not be used for anything important.
